# Use C# to read handedness setting from Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows

On Windows 8 I'm trying to determine what the handedness of the mouse is using C#. In other words, I'm trying to read this setting:

> Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Mouse -> Switch primary and secondary
>   buttons.

I've tried using WMI but with no luck. The handedness property value is always null, whatever mouse I use.

```
SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_PointingDevice");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery);

foreach (var mouse in searcher.Get())
{
    foreach (var property in mouse.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
    }
}
```

Are there any other ways to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that GetSystemMetrics, exposed on user32.dll can be used to return the swapped mouse button data you seek. Here are some references and a quick console app thrown together for testing. The 3rd link contains some more 'official' examples of how to use GetSystemMetrics with C#.

[GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Wrong way to detect swapped mouse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071017-00/?p=24753)

[Reference for constants, etc](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClientsideProviders/MS/Win32/NativeMethods.cs,1762fb4aeed96468)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 GetSystemMetrics(Int32 bSwap);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //normally you would make this as a constant:
            int SM_SWAPBUTTON = 23;

            int isLeftHanded = GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON);
            //0 means not swapped, 1 means swapped (left handedness?)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The NativeMethods.cs can also lead you to this code: bool mouseSwapped = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetSystemMetrics(NativeMethods.SM_SWAPBUTTON) != 0;