# How can you detect if the mouse buttons are swapped on Windows from Python?

Tags: python, winapi, mouse

Left-handed users may have swapped the mouse buttons on Windows by setting the primary button to the right mouse button instead of the left. What Python code will let me detect this setting?

There are similar questions for C++ and C#:

[Use C# to read handedness setting from Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997186/use-c-sharp-to-read-handedness-setting-from-windows-8/34997444#34997444)

[Check if mouse buttons are swapped or not in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627956/check-if-mouse-buttons-are-swapped-or-not-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

This function will return `True` if the mouse buttons have been swapped and `False` if not:

```
import ctypes

def mouse_is_swapped():
    # GetSystemMetrics() with SM_SWAPBUTTON docs from MSDN: "Nonzero if the meanings of the left and right mouse buttons are swapped; otherwise, 0."
    SM_SWAPBUTTON = 23
    return ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON) != 0
```

This code only uses the standard library and doesn't require any third-party packages such as pywin32.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself writing a comment that explains what a particular value means, scrap the comment and introduce a symbolic constant instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple single line ways to GET or SET the mouse swap in Python.

To get: `win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_SWAPBUTTON)`
To set: `win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP,1)` (0 to unswap)

Alternatively:
To get: `ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_SWAPBUTTON)`
To set: `ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(win32con.SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP,1,0,0)`

[SM_SWAPBUTTON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics#SM_SWAPBUTTON)

> Nonzero if the meanings of the left and right mouse buttons are swapped; otherwise, 0.

[SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa#SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP):

> Swaps or restores the meaning of the left and right mouse buttons. The uiParam parameter specifies TRUE to swap the meanings of the buttons, or FALSE to restore their original meanings.
> To retrieve the current setting, call GetSystemMetrics with the SM_SWAPBUTTON flag.

Here's a simple script to swap the mouse button:

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui

swapped = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_SWAPBUTTON)
win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP,not swapped)

input("Restored" if swapped else "Swapped")
```

To make the changes permanent (when you log back on) add these flags:

`flags = win32con.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | win32con.SPIF_SENDCHANGE`

```
win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP,1,flags)
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(win32con.SPI_SETMOUSEBUTTONSWAP,1,0,flags)
```